# Spring Batch - Retry mechanism for database restart

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am trying to handle reader failures during database restart. I tried with spring batch retry configuration. But I am getting SQL error saying connection is closed. Also c3p0 error as A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use. Can anyone please help me out to solve this? Is there any specific settings I need to do for c3p0?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring batch retry mechanism for reader failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680759/spring-batch-retry-mechanism-for-reader-failure)

Comment: I am not having problems in retry. During retry database connections are lost due to restart. Want to know how to solve that

Comment: I don't know about c3p0, but hikari automatically reconnect a lost connection. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356565/hikaricp-auto-reconnect