# Spring Batch DeadlockLoserDataAccessException

Tags: spring-batch

I'm using Spring Batch with partitioning. 
Initially, I was getting DeadlockLoserDataAccessException and then I have configured our steps as faultTolerant, please see the following code -

```
Step masterCalculationStep = stepBuilderFactory.get("STEP_1")
                   .<Map<Long, List<CostCalculation>>, List<TempCostCalc>>chunk(1).reader(reader)
                   .processor(processor)
                   .writer(writer)
                   .faultTolerant()
                   .retryLimit(5)
                   .retry(DeadlockLoserDataAccessException.class)
                   .build();
```

but now we are getting another exception -

> org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.NonSkippableReadException:
>   Non-skippable exception during read

Don't know why this new exception and how to resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried to declare the `DeadlockLoserDataAccessException` as skippable too?

Comment: No, I don't want to skip it :)

Comment: Please post the **full** stacktrace. Looks like this exception is thrown during reading. What is your item reader type?

Comment: Yes, Mahmoud you are right something wrong with reader, I'm using Custom ItemReader with jdbcTemplate. I will check further - Thank you for the hint. Hope I will figure it out now :) Stacktrace 
org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProvider.read(FaultTolerantChunkProvider.java:105)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:119)
 at  ....
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RetryPolicy` in a chunk oriented step is not applied to the reader. So if your reader might throw a transient exception, you need to add the retry logic around the reader yourself. This can be done for example with:

- AOP by applying `org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor` to your reader
- or by using `org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate` in a decorator of your reader that reties the `read` method when it throws a transient exception

Similar questions can be found here:

- [Spring batch retry mechanism for reader failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680759/spring-batch-retry-mechanism-for-reader-failure)
- [Retry in case of a failed reading](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/75256-retry-in-case-of-a-failed-reading)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Right now I'm not getting the transient exception but does it means that in case of DeadlockLoserDataAccessException  it will skip the records without any exception and job will complete successfully?   I was getting DeadlockLoserDataAccessException while writing records to the database using jdbctemple and want retry insertion only ? Does it possible ?

Comment: `I was getting DeadlockLoserDataAccessException while writing records` you said you are getting this exception while reading. If it occurs while writing, then the `RetryPolicy` will be applied by the fault tolerant step.